# Basic geometry: How to determine if a line passes through centre of circle

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

I have a line parameterized on `rho` and `theta`.

I have a circle parameterized on its `centre` and `radius`.

I want to check if the line passes through the center of the circle (with some error).

How do I efficiently compute this?

Comment: Check if the line intersects the circle by setting the two equations equal. If they intersect with two points of incidence, then check to see if the distance between them is equal to the diameter of the circle. If so, then the line passes through the center of the circle.

Comment: If you want to see if a point is on a line couldn't you just plug in the coordinates and see if it gives a consistent result?

Comment: Can you tell us what $\rho$ and $\theta$ denote here?

Answer (score 0):

You have the coordinates of the center in Cartesian coordinates.

All you have to do is to find the polar coordinates of the center and plug these coordinates into the equation of the line.

If the center is on the line then the coordinates of the center will satisfy the equation of the line otherwise it will not.

You do not need the radius of the circle to verify that the center is on the line.